Aligning axes in two graphics vertically in Tikz
I have two graphics side by side, and I want to align the $\alpha$ axes in both of the graphics vertically.

Here is my MWE.
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,reqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\definecolor{mc1}{rgb}{0.368417,0.506779,0.709798}
\definecolor{mc2}{rgb}{0.880722,0.611041,0.142051}
\definecolor{mc3}{rgb}{0.560181,0.691569,0.194885}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\n{2}
    \begin{axis}[
      width=8cm,
      height=6cm,
      axis x line=middle,
      xmin=-0.2,
      xmax=2.5,
      xtick={0,1,1.5,2},
      xticklabels={$0$,$1$,$\tfrac{2n-1}{2(n-1)}$,$\tfrac{n}{n-1}$},
      xlabel=$\alpha$,
      every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west},
      axis y line=middle,
      ymin=-0.2,
      ymax=3.25,
      ytick={0,1,\n},
      yticklabels={$0$,$1$,$n$},
      ylabel=$\beta$,
      every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south}
    ]
      \addplot[name path=xia,draw=none,domain=0:\n/(\n-1)]{3.1};
      \addplot[name path=xib,draw=none,domain=\n/(\n-1):2.4]{3.1};
      \addplot[name path=xoa,draw=none,domain=0:\n/(\n-1)]{0};
      \addplot[name path=xob,draw=none,domain=\n/(\n-1):2.4]{0};
      \addplot[name path=cc,domain=0:\n/(\n-1),samples=2,color=mc3,style=dashed,opacity=1,thick]{(\n-1)*(1-x)+1};
      \addplot[mc1!10] fill between [of=cc and xia];
      \addplot[mc1!10] fill between [of=xob and xib];
      \addplot[mc2!10] fill between[of=cc and xoa];
      \addplot[domain=1:(2*\n-1)/(2*(\n-1)),samples=2,color=mc2,style=solid,opacity=1]{1-2*(\n-1)*(x-1)};
      \draw[color=mc2] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,3.1);
      \draw[color=mc2] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:1,1);
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:0.25,0.5) {(a1)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:0.25,1.3) {(a2)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:0.5,2.25) {(a5)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:1.16,0.25) {(c1)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:1.6,0.17) {(c2)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:1.75,1.5) {(c5)};
      \draw[color=gray] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:0.95,0.05) -- (axis cs:0.95,0.45) -- (axis cs:0.9,0.5) -- (axis cs:0.95,0.55) -- (axis cs:0.95,0.95) -- (axis cs:1,1);
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:0.75,0.5) {(b1)};
      \draw[color=gray] (axis cs:1,1) -- (axis cs:1.05,1.05) -- (axis cs:1.05,2) -- (axis cs:1.1,2.05) -- (axis cs:1.05,2.1) -- (axis cs:1.05,3.05) -- (axis cs:1,3.1);
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:1.25,2.05) {(b2)};
      \draw[radius=1pt,color=mc2,fill=mc2!10] (axis cs:1,1) circle;
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \qquad
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\n{2}
    \begin{axis}[
      width=8cm,
      height=6cm,
      axis x line=middle,
      xmin=-0.2,
      xmax=2.6,
      xtick={0,1},
      xticklabels={$0$,$1$},
      xlabel=$\alpha$,
      every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west},
      axis y line=middle,
      ymin=-0.2,
      ymax=2.35,
      ytick={0},
      yticklabels={$0$},
      ylabel=$\lambda$,
      every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south}
    ]
      \addplot[name path=xi,draw=none,domain=0:2.5]{2.25};
      \addplot[name path=xo,draw=none,domain=0:2.5]{0};
      \addplot[name path=cc,domain=0:2.5,samples=50,color=mc1,style=solid,opacity=1,thick]{(1-x)^\n};
      \addplot[mc1!10] fill between [of=cc and xo];
      \addplot[mc2!10] fill between [of=cc and xi];
      \draw[color=mc2] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,2.25);
      \draw[radius=2pt,color=red,fill=mc1!10] (axis cs:1,0) circle;
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:0.5,1.25) {(a3)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:0.2,0.2) {(a4)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:1.55,1.25) {(c3)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:2.2,0.5) {(c4)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  %\caption{}\label{}
\end{figure}

\end{document} 


Off topic, you should set axis on top.

You could place both plots in the same tikzpicture:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,reqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\definecolor{mc1}{rgb}{0.368417,0.506779,0.709798}
\definecolor{mc2}{rgb}{0.880722,0.611041,0.142051}
\definecolor{mc3}{rgb}{0.560181,0.691569,0.194885}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\n{2}
    \begin{axis}[
      name=quack,
      width=8cm,
      height=6cm,
      axis x line=middle,
      xmin=-0.2,
      xmax=2.5,
      xtick={0,1,1.5,2},
      xticklabels={$0$,$1$,$\tfrac{2n-1}{2(n-1)}$,$\tfrac{n}{n-1}$},
      xlabel=$\alpha$,
      every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west},
      axis y line=middle,
      ymin=-0.2,
      ymax=3.25,
      ytick={0,1,\n},
      yticklabels={$0$,$1$,$n$},
      ylabel=$\beta$,
      every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south},
    ]
      \addplot[name path=xia,draw=none,domain=0:\n/(\n-1)]{3.1};
      \addplot[name path=xib,draw=none,domain=\n/(\n-1):2.4]{3.1};
      \addplot[name path=xoa,draw=none,domain=0:\n/(\n-1)]{0};
      \addplot[name path=xob,draw=none,domain=\n/(\n-1):2.4]{0};
      \addplot[name path=cc,domain=0:\n/(\n-1),samples=2,color=mc3,style=dashed,opacity=1,thick]{(\n-1)*(1-x)+1};
      \addplot[mc1!10] fill between [of=cc and xia];
      \addplot[mc1!10] fill between [of=xob and xib];
      \addplot[mc2!10] fill between[of=cc and xoa];
      \addplot[domain=1:(2*\n-1)/(2*(\n-1)),samples=2,color=mc2,style=solid,opacity=1]{1-2*(\n-1)*(x-1)};
      \draw[color=mc2] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,3.1);
      \draw[color=mc2] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:1,1);
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:0.25,0.5) {(a1)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:0.25,1.3) {(a2)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:0.5,2.25) {(a5)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:1.16,0.25) {(c1)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:1.6,0.17) {(c2)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:1.75,1.5) {(c5)};
      \draw[color=gray] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:0.95,0.05) -- (axis cs:0.95,0.45) -- (axis cs:0.9,0.5) -- (axis cs:0.95,0.55) -- (axis cs:0.95,0.95) -- (axis cs:1,1);
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:0.75,0.5) {(b1)};
      \draw[color=gray] (axis cs:1,1) -- (axis cs:1.05,1.05) -- (axis cs:1.05,2) -- (axis cs:1.1,2.05) -- (axis cs:1.05,2.1) -- (axis cs:1.05,3.05) -- (axis cs:1,3.1);
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:1.25,2.05) {(b2)};
      \draw[radius=1pt,color=mc2,fill=mc2!10] (axis cs:1,1) circle;
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
      width=8cm,
      height=6cm,
      axis x line=middle,
      xmin=-0.2,
      xmax=2.6,
      xtick={0,1},
      xticklabels={$0$,$1$},
      xlabel=$\alpha$,
      every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west},
      axis y line=middle,
      ymin=-0.2,
      ymax=2.35,
      ytick={0},
      yticklabels={$0$},
      ylabel=$\lambda$,
      every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south},
      at={(quack.right of origin)},
      xshift=1cm,
      anchor=left of origin,
    ]
      \addplot[name path=xi,draw=none,domain=0:2.5]{2.25};
      \addplot[name path=xo,draw=none,domain=0:2.5]{0};
      \addplot[name path=cc,domain=0:2.5,samples=50,color=mc1,style=solid,opacity=1,thick]{(1-x)^\n};
      \addplot[mc1!10] fill between [of=cc and xo];
      \addplot[mc2!10] fill between [of=cc and xi];
      \draw[color=mc2] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,2.25);
      \draw[radius=2pt,color=red,fill=mc1!10] (axis cs:1,0) circle;
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:0.5,1.25) {(a3)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:0.2,0.2) {(a4)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:1.55,1.25) {(c3)};
      \node[draw=none] at (axis cs:2.2,0.5) {(c4)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  %\caption{}\label{}
\end{figure}

\end{document} 



Simply replace the \begin{tikzpicture} lines with \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}].

Would you be so kind and show a compilable example? I tried this earlier and the axis were not aligned: https://i.sstatic.net/cp5uuegY.png

Yes, you are right. Somehow, different values for ymax are creating trouble.
